# Selenium: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChomeDriver only supports Chrome version 102

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the program some error message is shown and the program can not be executed and the message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.sessionNotCreatedExeception:could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChomeDriver only supports Chrome version 102.
```

Chromedriver is not hitting the URL.

Comment: Update your `ChromeDriver` or downgrade your `Chrome` installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your chrome version does not match the version of your chrome webdriver. You have to download the right version of the webdriver. If you are not sure which version of Chrome are you running, you can find it in "about" section.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.sessionNotCreatedExeception:could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChomeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=102.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=102.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.61/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 102

- Presumably you are using the latest *chrome=104.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=102.0* and the *chrome=104.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.

Also ensure,

- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).